# Select2 plugin function undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am using select2 in my angular powered RoR application. When using jQuery to create select2 widget, I am getting select2 undefined error.

My bower.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "angular": "1.3.12",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.9.9",
    "select2": "3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.2",
    "rxjs": "2.3"
  }
}
```

Layout and js includes

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery/dist/jquery.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'angular/angular.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rxjs/dist/rx.all.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'select2/select2.js' %>
```

$('select').select2() will throw an exception, because select2 is not defined.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `select2` before including it. Try to change .js file inclusion order and see. It should work.

Comment: That's not the case. I tried to introspect for select2() on jQuery object in Chrome JS debugger and it's not there either.